# What is the exactly Runtime Host?

Tags: c#, process, clr, runtime

What is the exactly definition of Runtime Host?

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a51xd4ze.aspx):

> The common language runtime has been designed to support a variety of different types of applications, from Web server applications to applications with a traditional rich Windows user interface. Each type of application requires a runtime host to start it. The runtime host loads the runtime into a process, creates the application domains within the process, and loads user code into the application domains.

So is it a process which loads the runtime into another process?
How do I check it in Task Manager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's a process that loads the runtime DLLs ( e.g. mscoree.dll, etc ) into its process space.

So there is only 1 process space.

The runtime that is referred to is really the .Net runtime or CLR.   And from a simplified traditional OS point of view, the CLR is really just a set of DLLs.  So, you need a OS process to load and execute the entry point of that DLL.  This **hosting** executable is your runtime host.  In reality the .Net runtime host does a lot of things for the CLR ( See [Hosting Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaf1h1h5.aspx)  )

You mentioned MSDN, so I guess you've looked at [Runtime Hosts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a51xd4ze.aspx) on there.  You can see the examples they give are all executables that host the CLR ( DLLs ).

Hope that helps.

Comment: so is it the OS loader which spawns the host process?

Comment: Yes, The hosting process is started like any other process.  Basically, what makes it a .Net runtime host is that it loads the CLR.

Answer (score 4):

This article might help: [Implementing a custom runtime host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301479.aspx). It discusses the various aspects of the host and when/why you might want to implement your own.

Lifted directly from the article:
examples of hosts that ship with the .NET Framework include:

- ASP.NET: An ISAPI filter that ships
  with ASP.NET is responsible for
  starting the CLR and initializing the
  plumbing needed to route Web requests
  to the ASP.NET processes.
- Internet Explorer: The .NET Framework ships
  with a MIME filter that hooks into
  Internet Explorer 5.01 or later to
  execute managed code controls that
  are referenced from HTML pages.
- Shell Executables: Each time an
  executable is launched from the
  shell, a small piece of unmanaged
  code gets invoked that transitions
  control to the CLR.

Other hosts could include:

- Database Engines A future version of
  Microsoft SQL Server will allow
  stored procedures to be written in
  languages that support the .NET
  Framework and are executed with the
  CLR.
- Personal Organizers Several
  e-mail/calendar/contact programs
  allow users to write scripts to
  customize the processing of e-mail
  messages, appointments, and so on.
  It's easy to imagine these scripts
  running on the CLR. The security
  system provided by the CLR is
  especially important in this scenario
  because of the proliferation of
  viruses spread by e-mail systems.