# Unmanaged components running Common Language Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I am a beginner in C#. In fact, just started learning the language few days back.
I am trying to build on the concept of the .NET Framework pertaining to C#.

I was reading about CLR here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/overview

What I don't understand is this part of text where author says:

> The .NET Framework can be hosted by unmanaged components that load the 
>       common language runtime into their processes and initiate the execution of 
>       managed code, thereby creating a software environment that exploits both 
>       managed and unmanaged features. The .NET Framework not only provides several 
>       runtime hosts but also supports the development of third-party runtime 
>       hosts.

My understanding of "unmanaged components" is that they are programs written in plain C/C++ using the native Windows API. So now these unmanaged programs can load the CLR DLL into their program address space and that can make CLR functions available, and then this unmanaged program can load a managed program executable using CLR functions. Is that correct?

If my understanding is correct, then I want to know in what cases would I do this? Or why would I want an unmanaged program to load the CLR and run managed code?

Also, what does the author mean by "The .NET Framework not only provides several
runtime hosts but also supports the development of third-party runtime hosts"?

I thought the CLR is the only runtime in the .NET Framework.

Comment: It seems to me that the quoted paragraph answers your first questions precisely: _"thereby creating a software environment that exploits both managed and unmanaged features"_. Why would _you_ want to do that? Only _you_ can say. As for the runtime hosts, the CLR is the runtime. A runtime host is something that _hosts_ the runtime. The CLR doesn't host itself. See e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a51xd4ze(v=vs.100).aspx and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286160/what-is-the-exactly-runtime-host

Comment: In the first part of my question, I was looking for a response in terms of if someone in their vast experience of working with .Net C# actually used the feature ( running managed code from inside unmanaged app). Anyways.

Thanks for the links. Explains good.

Comment: I have created a DLL that provided an API for both managed and unmanaged code. You could use in in say c# just like any other .Net dll. However we had customers using Delphi or unmanaged C++. Lots of other languages still provide a way to import functions from dll's with C style exports (stdcall or cdecl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally Windows was all unmanaged code. So it would have loaded the .net framework to allow managed code to run. From a maintenance point of view it is best to have managed code. However you don't want to throw away millions of lines of unmanaged working code. If Microsoft did not provide this functionality users would have had to re-write everything. (don't rewrite everything see link). Rather than do this users would have just ignored .net.
https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/