# What Exactly is a Runtime host in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

The MSDN Website says that .NET Frameworks Includes few Runtime hosts in it and ASP.NET is one of them.

The definition Below for ASP.NET is taken from MSDN :
ASP.NET : Loads the Runtime into the process that is to handle the Web request. ASP.NET also creates an application domain for each Web application that will run on a Web server.

The Question that i have at the moment is:
Is the Process that loads the CLR and runs the ASP.NET OR ASP.NET MVC Application is Runtime host.

Because w3wp.exe is a process that does that. Does this make w3wp.exe a Runtime host. If not, then what Exactly is the .exe or .dll(or a set of .dll) in ASP.NET that makes it a Runtime host

Comment: may or may not be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286160/what-is-the-exactly-runtime-host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what Exactly is the .exe or .dll(or a set of .dll) in ASP.NET that makes it a Runtime host

The System.Web.dll is the core in the asp.net framework which contains the main run-time for asp.net and asp.net-mvc based applications.

You can refer to the following for details on what the run-time consists of:

http://diranieh.com/NETASP/HttpRuntime.htm